# Python conditional import & resources

Tags: python, import, resources, conditional-statements

I know it is possible to conditionally import modules. My question is; if the condition to import a module is false, will the module still be loaded (and just sit idle in the background), or not.

I ask this from a resource point of view. Using a Raspberry Pi for programming does have its limits for example. This is just a hypothetical question... I haven't run into any problems yet.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not imported, and it is not loaded.

This code verifies that the module is not added to the namespace:

```
>>> if False:
...     import time
... else:
...     time.clock()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

And this code proves that the `import` statement is never run, as otherwise it would have generated an `ImportError`. This means that the module is never loaded in `sys.modules`, the [cache (in the memory)](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) of all modules that have been imported previously.

```
>>> if False:
...     import thismoduledoesnotexist
...
>>> import thismoduledoesnotexist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named thismoduledoesnotexist
```

This is mainly due to the fact that all that Python does prior to running the script is compile it to *bytecode*, and as such does not evaluate the statements before their occurence.

Comment: you can also check sys.modules if the module was loaded.

Comment: @GabrielSamfira you commented while I was editing my answer :)